# Anyone aware of an alternative solution to ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac

When changing Mac OS X network MAC address:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether 12:34:56:78:90:ab
```

, error occured:

> “ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Can’t assign requested address”

Solution:
-- Disassociate with SSID

```
sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport en0 -z
```

-- Change MAC

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether 12:34:56:78:90:ab
```

When disassociating with SSID, what steps can be taken to make changing MAC address more concise & efficient?

Comment: This does not work in Mac OS Ventura on the M1/M2 architecture MacBooks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these steps described in your question to no avail.
My solution was to install via homebrew:

```
brew install spoof-mac
```

Then I disabled Wi-Fi:

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

and

```
sudo spoof-mac randomize en0
```

Be aware, that the mac-address seems not to be changed, when clicking with option on the Wi-Fi Icon. The actual Mac-Adress is shown in the Terminal

```
ifconfig en0
```

Have to verify it with Wireshark.